# Python modules matching a pattern

Tags: python

I'd like to run `doctest`s for a set of modules (glob: `invenio.webtag*`) from a single module, but I'll need a way to import all these (and only these) modules and run `doctest.testmod()` on all of them. Any ideas?

**Edit**: The solution:

```
import doctest
import glob
import os
import pkgutil
pkgpath = pkgutil.extend_path([], 'invenio')[0]
for module_path in glob.glob(pkgpath + '/webtag*.py'):
    module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(module_path))[0]
    module = __import__('invenio.' + module_name)
    doctest.testmod(module)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module can be dynamically loaded using `__import__` e.g.

```
my_module = __import__("mymodule")
```

and then passed to `testmod` e.g.

```
doctest.testmod(my_module)
```

Assuming you can build a list of the matching modules using either [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) or filtering the results from [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) you should be able to use this approach.

**Update:**

To import `invenio.webtag` try using a *fromlist*:

```
module = __import__('invenio.webtag', globals(), locals(), ['invenio'], -1)
```

see [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) for the explanation.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Now I just have to figure out why this piece of code imports `invenio` instead of `invenio.webtag`: `module = __import__('invenio.webtag')`

Comment: @l0b0: From the `__import__` docs: "When importing a module from a package, note that __import__('A.B', ...) returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when fromlist is not empty."

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to import a submodule. Pär added a comment saying the same thing whilst I was doing the edit.